# Google reCaptcha doesn't load on first page load

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, recaptcha

I'm using Google reCaptcha in my company website, it works fine on chrome, firefox and ie11, but it doesn't load on the first page load on the android browser but appears on refreshing the page...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing a window.onload statement I had on the page, I suspect Google recaptcha uses the same statement in their script and 2 window.onload statements on the same page somehow confuses the Android browser...